# Compare 4 variables to find the lowest C++

Tags: c++

I want to find the lowest number of the four, but this looks kinda wierd , isnt there a smarter and shorter way to do it?

That is what I have:

```
int findlowest(int one, int two, int three, int four) {
    int output = one //as of now , we will be outputting one , except if we find a lower score.
    if(output > two) { out = two;} // if output is proven to be bigger than two, two is our new output.
    if(output > three){ output = three;} //same operation with three
    if(output > four){ output = four;} // same operation with four
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
std::min(a, std::min(b, std::min(c, d)));
```

Include `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Crap you beat me by 7 seconds, and mine had a mistake!

Comment: is the balanced tree better `std::min(std::min(a,b), std::min(c, d));`?

Comment: @osgx: No functional difference.

Comment: @osgx: None. Why would there be any difference?

Comment: because std::min(a,b) and std::min(c, d) in my version can be done in parallel.

Comment: @osgx: Compare generated assembly for both. It'll be near identical (order of some instructions might be bit different, but there is exactly the same number of branches and comparisons).

Comment: @CatPlusPlus let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1143/discussion-between-osgx-and-cat-plus-plus)

Answer (score 15):

c++11:

```
int minimum = std::min( { 1,2,3,4,5 } );
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? gcc 4.6 with -std=c++0x doesn't like this.

Comment: @juanchopanza Works fine with g++4.5

Comment: That's 5 values. How do you do 4, like was asked for? :-)

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I used to write my own variadic `min`, but this is much better!

Answer (score 10):

```
min_int = min(min(one, two), min(three, four));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int minimum = *std::min_element(a, a+5);
```

Comment: This version of `std::min_element` returns an "iterator" to the position of the minimum, so you need to dereference it.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of answers saying to use the Standard library facilities - they're right, it covers this case!  But, for the educational value, here's a slightly more concise way to do what you were doing:

```
int findlowest(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int of_a_b = a < b ? a : b;
    int of_c_d = c < d ? c : d;
    return of_a_b < of_c_d ? of_a_b : of_c_d;
}
```

Easily generalised for different types (though C++03 doesn't make it easy to generalise for arbitrary numbers of arguments):

```
template <typename T>
T findlowest(const T& a, const T& b, const T& c, const T& d)
{
    const T& of_a_b = a < b ? a : b;
    const T& of_c_d = c < d ? c : d;
    return of_a_b < of_c_d ? of_a_b : of_c_d;
}
```

Comment: 1) How do you convert `T a` to `int of_a_b`? 2) your `of_*` should be const.

Comment: Kerrek: 1) well spotted, thanks. 2) actually, I'll change them to const references so there's no potential copy invoked there.  Cheers.